# JSON.stringify - accessing data

Tags: json

So I have Json obj which I convert via JSON.stringfy and the result is:

```
{
  "data" : [ {
    "id" : 417206355511802,
    "name" : "test01"
  }, {
    "id" : 421211003974634,
    "name" : "test02"
  }, {
    "id" : 403713622404901,
    "name" : "test03"
  }]
}
```

How can I access each name value? I was trying:

var test = result[0].name;
   alert(test);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access anything from the result of `stringify()` - it produces a string, hence its name. Rather, it sounds like you started with a string and converted it to an *object* via `JSON.parse()`.

If that's not the case, and you already have the object, you don't need to stringify if you want to access properties.

That out of the way, you're missing the `data` step.

```
myobj.data[0].name; //<-- where myobj is the variable holding the object
```

Comment: so it should be:                  var test = data[0].name;
   alert(test);   ?

Comment: It should be `myobj.data[0].name`, where `myobj` is the variable the object is stored in, whatever you've called it.

Comment: I have related question, so I'll try here instead of creating new question. Is it possible to count elements "name" in this object withour for loop?

Comment: Well surely that's the same as asking how many elements are in the array, since all elements have a `name` property. In which case, `myobj.data.length`

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify will not help you.becouse it's give a string as output.you can directly access the object elements by

```
var arr = myObj.data;
arr.forEach(function(elem)     { 
      console.log(elem.id);
      console.log(elem.name);
});
```